# Ext of modification of vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a curve and $x \in X$ a closed point.
Suppose we have a modification of vector bundles on $X$, which is a short exact sequence of $\newcommand\mc{\mathcal} \mc O_X$-modules
$$0\to \mc E \to \mc F \to j_*V \to 0$$
where $j : \{x\} \to X$ is the inclusion of a closed point, $\mc E, \mc F$ are locally free $\mc O_X$-modules and $V$ is a vector space over the residue field $\kappa(x)$.

Then suppose $W$ is another $\kappa(x)$-vector space, and we consider the $\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext}\DeclareMathOperator{\Mor}{Mor}$ long exact sequence associated to $\Mor(i_*W,{-})$:

$$ 0 \to \Mor(i_*W,\mc E) \to \Mor(i_*W,\mc F) \to \Mor(i_*W,i_*V) \to \Ext^1(i_*W,\mc E) \to \dots $$

As there are no non-trivial maps from a skyscraper sheaf to a locally free sheaf, we
have $\Mor(i_*W,\mc F) = 0$, leading to an injection $\Mor(i_*W,i_*V) \to \Ext^1(i_*W,\mc E)$.
Is this last map also surjective, hence an isomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(i_*W,i_*V) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(W,V)
$$
has dimension $\dim(W)\dim(V)$ over the residue field of a point, while the space
$$
\mathrm{Ext}^1(i_*W,\mathcal{E}) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(W,i^*\mathcal{E})
$$
has dimension $\dim(W)\mathrm{rank}(\mathcal{E})$, so this map is **not** an isomorphism unless $\mathrm{rank}(\mathcal{E}) = \dim(V)$.

Comment: Thank you! How can one see the isomorphism $\mathrm{Ext}^1(i_*W,\mathcal{E}) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(W,i^*\mathcal{E})$?

Comment: Use Serre duality and an isomorphism $i^*\omega_X \cong \mathcal{O}_X$.